# Deleting classes from an unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

Is it possible to delete an Apex class from an unlocked package?

I have deleted a class from the sfdx project for an locked package. Then I've successfully created the new package version.

However, when I deploy the package to the new org, I am getting `Apex compile failure` error messages telling me that the Apex class that I have just deleted can't find some references and types that were in the old package, and are not in the new one.

Perhaps I need to uninstall the old package version from the environment before reinstalling the new one?

Comment: Is it unlocked, or unmanaged package?

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Ah. It's a 2nd Generation Unlocked package. Thanks. I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **--upgradetype Delete** in your force:package:install command.

Documentation in here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_install_pkg_upgrade.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot :)